# iOS - 'Pan' navigation flow with Custom Transitions

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, custom-transition

I'm trying to use iOS7's custom transitions in order to let the user navigate between view controllers through a kind of 'pan' effect.

As depicted here:

[image]

I need the background pattern to continue also outside the vc's bounds, so that when the user moves from vc1 to vc2 all the background visible between the vcs translates too.

Any hint is really appreciated.

Thanks,
DAN

Comment: You can use transition effects rather.

Comment: Do you mean the transitionFromView method of UIView?
How would that resolve the background issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a large `UIImageView` with the image in the `transitionContext.containerView`, and change its origin as the pan gesture progresses?

Comment: Awesome, it seems to work brilliantly!
Is it correct to add the UIImageView in the
animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext method, as it is called when the animation starts,
or there is an initialization point for the transitionContext object?

Comment: @DAN Yes that's the method where all your animation code goes. And if the answer works, you should accept it :)

Comment: Thanks perfect, my only concern was about allocating an object and adding it as a subview in a method which is called when the user interaction begins; I hope it does not slow down the transition.

Comment: I do plenty of object creation in my transition animation code. Animations still work smoothly.